# Obtain a triangular mesh from trivariate grid points in R

Tags: r, mesh, rgl

I am getting familiar with 3D representations. I want to check if a set of trivariate data points falls inside an specific region. For gaussian data this may be easily done using something like:

```
data = cbind(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
inside = data[,1]^2+data[,2]^2 + data[,3]^2 <= qchisq(0.95,3)
which(inside==T)
```

But, how can I do this manually? There is an R package called library(ptinpoly) to do so, but it requires a Triangular mesh, and I do not know how to obtain a triangular mesh these trivariate grid points.

```
b = 30
x = seq(0,1,length.out = b)
grid = expand.grid(x,x)
u = grid[,1]
v = grid[,2]
theta <- 2 * pi * u
phi   <- acos(2 * v - 1) 
  
tau = 0.95
polygon =(t(c(0,0,0) + sqrt(qchisq(tau,3))*t(chol(diag(1,3)))%*%
                rbind(sin(phi) * cos(theta) ,sin(theta) * sin(phi),cos(phi))))

require(rgl)
plot3d(polygon,col="grey")
```

Any clue?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here.  Is your region always a sphere?  Is it always convex?  A collection of points isn't enough by itself to specify a region; you need to know how they are joined up.